# Using Flatten to select where var1 (non-repeated) = "abc" from a bigquery table which contains multiple nested variables?

Tags: google-analytics, nested, google-bigquery, flatten

I'm fairly new to BigQuery (3rd day of using it with no training), I'm just trying to get my head around nested fields etc.

I've looked at the following resources and used the personsdata example on the google bigquery docs link

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data

https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-flatten-data-using-google-bigquerys-legacy-vs-standard-sql/

I'd like to run the below query:

```
select *
from [dataset.tableid]
where fullname = 'John Doe'
```

If I run this, I get the following error:

*Error: Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time. Found children_age and citiesLived_place*

From reading the above articles this isn't possible because you need to flatten the results, which from what I can understand just duplicates all the none repeated variables i.e.

Fullname |  age |  gender |  Children.name |  children.age

**John Doe |  22  |  Male**   |  John          |  5

**John Doe |  22  |  Male**   |  Jane          |  7

One of the above articles suggests that you can still use the where statements by using the flatten function in bigquery:

```
select fullname,
age,
gender,
citiesLived.place
FROM (FLATTEN([dataset.tableId], children))
WHERE
(citiesLived.yearLived > 1995) AND
(children.age > 3)
GROUP BY fullName, age, gender, citiesLived.place
```

If I change this to:

```
select *
FROM (FLATTEN([dataset.tableId], children))
WHERE fullname = 'John Doe'
```

Then this works fine and gives me what I need however if I change to this:

```
select *
FROM (FLATTEN([dataset.tableId], citieslived))
WHERE fullname = 'John Doe'
```

Then I get the following error:

*Error: Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time. Found children_age and citiesLived_yearsLived*

Can someone explain why this will work flattening based on "Children" but not "CitiesLived" and how to know what variables to use within flatten with more complex datasets with multiple nested variables?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there a reason to try to do this using legacy SQL? I would suggest using standard SQL instead, since it makes array-based transformations easier to express.

Comment: Hi Elliott, thanks for your quick response, sorry, I wasn't even aware than bigquery had two SQL dialects.  Let me have a look into this to see about migrating and why we use the legacy language.  If you have any pointers on using the standard SQL then please let me know.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain why this will work flattening based on "Children" but not "CitiesLived"

Check schema of this table again

```
                Schema                
  ----------------------------------- 
   |- kind: STRING                    
   |- fullName: STRING (required)
   |- age: INTEGER
   |- gender: STRING
   +- phoneNumber: RECORD
   |  |- areaCode: INTEGER
   |  |- number: INTEGER
   +- children: RECORD (repeated)
   |  |- name: STRING
   |  |- gender: STRING
   |  |- age: INTEGER
   +- citiesLived: RECORD (repeated)
   |  |- place: STRING
   |  +- yearsLived: INTEGER (repeated)
```

As you can see - when you flatten `children` repeated record – the only repeated record that is left for output is `citiesLived` and even though it has inside it yet another repeated field – `yearsLived` – they are **not independent** – thus BigQuery Legacy SQL can output result

Now, when you flatten by `citiesLived` – what you get in result are two repeated fileds  - `children` and `yearsLived`. Those two are **independent** - thus BigQuery Legacy SQL cannot output such result.

> how to know what variables to use within flatten with more complex datasets with multiple nested variables?

To make it work - you should add yet another flattening with (for example) `yearsLived` filed. Something like below

```
FROM (FLATTEN(FLATTEN([dataset.tableId], citieslived), yearsLived))
```

Adding all those multiple FLATTENs can become cumbersome so using BigQuery Standard SQL is really the way to go!

See [Migrating from Legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) to [BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Mikhail! Am I right is saying that if there are dependent fields related to the field that you are flattening they you have to specify and flatten all these dependent fields?  I wasn't aware that there were two dialects of SQL in bigquery.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Legacy SQL has no problem to output repeated fields if they are dependent. You need to flatten those which are independent. But, still  - the best way to go from here - is to move to BigQuery Standard SQL. It has much better way of dealing with records. Take a look at ARRAYs to have an idea - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays

Comment: Thank you for this Mikhail, I've just tried using standard SQL to select from  one of our live bigquery dataset however I'm getting the following error: Error: Syntax error: Unexpected floating point literal "8286363." at [2:6].  I'm not sure if you'd be able to shed any light on this error but I'm guessing this is because we've named our dataset "8286363" and bigquery can only handle datasets which start with characters?

Comment: You should post new question with specific issue you have  - so we will be able to answer it. Comments do not allow answering effectively and is not really how SO operates. it is more question / answer site and not a discussion forum. So post new question. Meantime take one answer and accept it if it answered you current question. hope this makes sense to you :o)

Comment: meantime  - i think your guess is correct  - you can check more here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical

Comment: Hi mikhail, sorry this is my first time using SO as well, I'll remember this for next time, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this query:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(FLATTEN((FLATTEN(([project_id:dataset_id.table]), citiesLived.yearsLived)), citiesLived))
```

It will flatten as expected.

When using the Legacy SQL, BQ tries to [flatten automatically](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#flatten) the results for you.

What I have noticed though is that if you try to flatten repeated fields that have other repeated fields inside then sometimes you might run into these errors (notice that the fields `citiesLived` and `citiesLived.yearsLived` are both repeated).

So one way to solve that is by forcing the flatten operation on all repeated fields you want to work with (in the example I showed you I first flattened the *yearsLived* and then *citiesLived*) and not relying on the automatic flattening operation that the Legacy SQL offers.

But what I strongly recommend and encourage you to do is to learn the **Standard SQL** version for BQ as Elliot suggested in his comment. It might have a steeper learning curve at first but it will totally pay off in the long run (and you won't have the risk of eventually having to migrate all your legacy queries to standard as we had to do in our company)

Comment: Thank you for the advice Will, I didn't realise that SQL had two dialects in bigquery.  I'll have a further look into migrating to standard SQL.